# Remote access to virtual machines

Tags: vmware, remote-access, vmware-player

Hi I have a desktop with WMware Workstation player on it. I've installed a few virtual machines for school (Ubuntu, Windows 8.1, ...). Is there a way to access them remotely? Without installing Teamviewer or VNC on every machine? I can install it on the host, but i don't want access to my whole computer remotely.

Comment: This is not a programming question..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access win 8.1 with RDP that is enabled by default. for Ubuntu you can install XRDP to access the same way. However - you need to make sure that the source host can be access the internal VM's by mean of IP connectivity (routing)

Comment: But then I need to make sure all the VM's are online before I leave home. Or is there a way to power them remotely?

Comment: You will have to leave it on so it will be ready to accept incoming connections: the Host and the VM's . The VM's should have internet connection and you need to map TCP ports on your router external interface (TCP/3389 for both RDP and XRDP). pay attention to create a Bridge adapter between Host <--> VM , it will make your life easier . Assuming the Host PC is 10.0.0.10 and VM-a = 10.0.0.1 and VM-b = 10.0.0.2 and the router is 10.0.0.100 : then you need to map : router-public:3389 --> 10.0.0.1:3389 , router-public:3390 --> 10.0.0.2:3389

Comment: you can check this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViiwOGQTBHw it will be useful to be able using RDP and port forwarding to access remotely your network and if you try to turn on your pc remotely you can using wake on lan feature .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - you have to use SSH.

http://www.openssh.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not to state the obvious, why not use SSH, just command line access not a full a UI?

I haven't used this myself but I hear this is a good option for windows http://www.freesshd.com/

As for Ubuntu:

sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install openssh-server
  sudo ufw allow 22

Comment: The problem is that I need the GUI for class, I have a Macbook (with a small SSD). So when i have a class about "using Windows" I need to access the GUI.